# Custom Django Signals Not Working

Tags: django, django-signals, django-rq

I realize there are many other questions related to custom django signals that don't work, and believe me, I have read all of them several times with no luck for getting my personal situation to work.

Here's the deal: I'm using django-rq to manage a lengthy background process that is set off by a particular http request. When that background process is done, I want it to fire off a custom Django signal so that the django-rq can be checked for any job failure/exceptions.

Two applications, both on the INSTALLED_APPS list, are at the same level. Inside of app1 there is a file:
**signals.py**

```
import django.dispatch

file_added = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["issueKey", "file"])
fm_job_done = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["jobId"])
```

and also a file **jobs.py**

```
from app1 import signals
from django.conf import settings

jobId = 23
issueKey = "fake"
fileObj = "alsoFake"

try:
    pass
finally:
    signals.file_added.send(sender=settings.SIGNAL_SENDER,issueKey=issueKey,fileName=fileObj)
    signals.fm_job_done.send(sender=settings.SIGNAL_SENDER,jobId=jobId)
```

then inside of app2, in **views.py**

```
from app1.signals import file_added, fm_job_done
from django.conf import settings

#Setup signal handlers
def fm_job_done_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print "hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
    logging.info("file manager job done signal fired")

def file_added_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print "hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
    logging.info("file added signal fired")

file_added.connect(file_added_callback,sender=settings.SIGNAL_SENDER,weak=False)
fm_job_done.connect(fm_job_done_callback,sender=settings.SIGNAL_SENDER,weak=False)
```

I don't get any feedback whatsoever though and am at a total loss. I know for fact that jobs.py is executing, and therefore also that the block of code that should be firing the signals is executing as well since it is in a finally block (no the try is not actually empty - I just put pass there for simplicity) Please feel free to ask for more information - I'll respond asap.

Comment: having the same problem, did you ever find a solution for this? It's definately an issue with django-rq as the signal receiver works fine with `async=False`

Comment: @SColvin Hi there. No I'm afraid I never did really find a solution. The below answer certainly did not solve my problem. I have since moved on to a different paradigm relying more heavily on django-rq and http requests.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for django > 2.0

1. settings.py:

> change name of your INSTALLED_APPS from 'app2' to
>   'app2.apps.App2Config'

2. app2 -> apps.py:

> from app1.signals import file_added, fm_job_done

```
Class App2Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app2'

    def ready(self):
        from .views import fm_job_done_callback, file_added_callback
        file_added.connect(file_added_callback)
        fm_job_done.connect(fm_job_done_callback)
```

Answer (score -1):

use django `receiver` decorator

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app1.signals import file_added, fm_job_done

@receiver(fm_job_done)
def fm_job_done_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print "helloooooooooooooo"


@receiver(file_added)
def file_added_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print "helloooooooooooooo"
```

Also, I prefer to handle signals in `models.py`

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly you mean by "handle signals in models.py"?

Comment: @pooley1994  define signals callbacks in models.py

Comment: Ok. Well just using the decorator instead of the original method didn't change anything sadly.